# What is the probability of getting any two numbers (the order is not important) in 4 rolls?

Tags: probability, statistics

A random number generator will generate a number randomly from 1 to 18 and remove the number generated every time from the pool of availble numbers to generate $(1-18)$. So, for example, if it rolls 1 on the first run then it will generate numbers from $(2-18)$, if it gets a 5 on the second run it will generate numbers from $(2-18)-(5)$, etc.

What is the probability of getting any two  numbers we choose (order wont matter) in 4 rolls ?
What is the probability of getting any three numbers we choose (order wont matter) in 4 rolls ?

From lurking around this forum i found this might be the probability  of getting any one number i choose in 4 rolls: $1-((17/18)^4)+4*((17/18)^3)*1/18=0,3915$.
I don't know if this is correct and im a bit at a loss on how to continue for the "any two numbers", maybe multiply it by the probability of getting any other number in another roll: $(1-((17/18)^4)+4*((17/18)^3)*1/18)*(1-((16/17)^4)+4*((16/17)^3)*1/17)=0,1611$ the number feels fine.
But i just don't know.

Thanks.

PS: But really, i arrived here because i was just wondering what is the probability of getting any set of 1, 2, 3 or 4 civilizations in your team when playing age of empires 2, 4vs4 random civs, it's not a matter of life or death, i guess i must have aspergers.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this yourself?

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{18}{2}$ pairs we could choose. Each set of four contains $\binom{4}{2}$ pairs. The probability we get a particular pair is $\dfrac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{18}{2}}$.

The same would apply to whatever set sizes and pool sizes you're using.